# Weird behaviour for radio buttons for ignored tag on localized sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, localization, ignored-tags

Switching mode for how the questions with ignored tags will be handled has weird visual behavior (blue circle size is too large) on localized sites, e.g. [ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/):

> [image: ruSO is ignored]

Seems this is happens due to the existence of the second line of option description.

Here is on MSE it looks valid:

> [image: MSE is good]

Comment: Was fixed with new responsive design.

Comment: @Suvitruf even when responsiveness is off.

Comment: I'm 99.9% certain this is fixed, but I can't run a full test suite with all browsers, so please let me know if it's still an issue.